# C++ хеш-таблица из индексов элементов другой структуры данных

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

У меня есть вектор, хранящий элементы, содержищие в себе поле `name`. Хочу создать хеш таблицу, обеспечивающую быстрый поиск по имени внутри вектора. Сама хеш таблица должна содержать только индексы и использовать строку в самих элементах при хешировании и сравнении. Хотелось бы использовать библиотечную реализацию хеш-таблицы, желательно boost. `std::unordered_set` при этом не подходит, т.к. невозможно(насколько я понимаю) определить хеш фунцию и функцию сравнения, работающую с внешними данными.

Comment: И зачем эти навороты? Храните сразу в `unordered_map`.

Comment: можно просто отсортировать вектор. А можно заморочится на префиксное дерево. Понять бы решаемую задачу...

Comment: @KoVadim, это учебное задание по сути - реализовать вектор(константное время доступа по индексу) с поиском по полю элемента за log(n), без оверхеда по памяти(нельзя рядом запилить unordered_map<string, index>)

Comment: Да и вообще интересно как определять более сложные функции хеширования и сравнения. Например, unordered_map требует создания временного объекта для поиска, что уже является значительным оверхедом, если объект большой, а мы ищем по строчке. Да и не все можно конструировать просто чтобы соблюдать интерфейс unordered_map

Comment: Сортированный вектор дает поиск за log(n)

Comment: @rewardealer кажется, Вы решили переоптимизировать. Сильно переоптимизировать. Скорее всего Ваше задание сильно проще.

Comment: @KoVadim, так и есть)) Уже второй день голову ломаю

Comment: У @Mikhailo правильный ответ для вашей задачи (а вот заголовок темы не раскрывает ее суть, а лишь сбивает с толку)

Answer (score 1):

Ваш комментарий уточнил задание, отвечаю на него.

Если вы отсортируете вектор, то получите то, что вам нужно -

1. доступ по индексу за константное время
2. поиск за время O(log(n))

Если это все требования - то вот оно решение.